# Segue passes null value on first tap. Works perfectly after that. Why?

Tags: storyboard, xcode4.5, segue

I'm a complete noob when it comes to xcode (started learning 3 weeks ago), PHP is my thing. Anyways, I'm trying to pass a value from a MasterViewController to a DetailViewController when somebody taps on a cell from a tableview ((which is being populated with data from a json file). The problem is that I get a null value the first time. It works perfectly after that.

This is my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

FetchDetails* item = _feed.items[indexPath.row];

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

UILabel *itemTitle = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
itemTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item.prodTitle];

UILabel *itemDate = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
itemDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item.prodDate];

UILabel *itemUser = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
itemUser.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"by %@", item.prodUser];

UIImageView *itemThumb = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
itemThumb.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: item.prodImage]]];
return cell;
}
```

The didSelectRowAtIndexPath. **item.prodId is part of the json but not displayed on the prototype cell. This is the value I need on the detailviewcontroller**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 FetchDetails* item = _feed.items[indexPath.row];
_selectedItem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item.prodId];
}
```

And the prepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showItemDetail"]) {

    DetailViewController *destVieController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destVieController.passedValue = _selectedItem;
    NSLog(@"%@", _selectedItem);

  }
}
```

I came up with all of this code after going through a couple of tutorials. I have no idea why It doesn't work the first time and works perfectly on the second click and so on. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Now that I think about it, it's not the segue that's passing the null value. prepareForSegue is the one getting the null value from didSelectRowAtIndexPath. So what I have to figure out is why _selectedItem is getting null when the user taps the first time.

Comment: After further testing, the values being passed are all over the place. Tapping on the first cell give me 1, then I click on the next value and it sends 1 too. When I click the second cell again, I get the correct value (2). 

It seems like it's getting the correct value only the second time. The first time you click on an item, _selectedItem doesn't get changed.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it. I had to stop using didSelectRowAtIndexpath and do everything in prepareForSegue.

This is the code I used on the segue:

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:99];

    DetailViewController *detailVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    detailVC.passedId = [label text];
```

As you can see, I got the prodId from a tagged label using viewWithTag.

Comment: Thank you! I just ran into the same issue. You saved me some headaches. :)